# JavaScript OnClick Select Tag Doesn't Work on Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, onclick, onselect

I have html and js (with jquery) code like this:

```
<label>Nationality</label>
<select name="user_nationality" class="input">
    <option value="1" selected onclick="$('#userphonearea').val('+62');">Indonesia</option>
    <optgroup label="Other Countries">
      <option value="2" onclick="$('#userphonearea').val('+44');">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="3" onclick="$('#userphonearea').val('+1');">United States of America</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<label>Phone Number</label>
<input type="text" name="user_phone_area" id="userphonearea" maxlength="5" size="5" value="" placeholder="+" required />
<input type="text" name="user_phone_number" maxlength="30" size="10" required />
```

I want to automatically input **user_phone_area** if I select **user_nationality**.
I used onclick, and it works on desktop browser. But it doesn't work on mobile browser such as android or iphone.

I try to change OnClick with OnSelect, but it doesn't work both on desktop and mobile

```
<select name="user_nationality" class="input">
    <option value="1" selected onselect="$('#userphonearea').val('+62');">Indonesia</option>
    <optgroup label="Other Countries">
      <option value="2" onselect="$('#userphonearea').val('+44');">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="3" onselect="$('#userphonearea').val('+1');">United States of America</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: This won't work in many browsers, you should attach eventhandlers to the `select` itself rather than `option`s.

Answer (score 2):

found answer for my own question

```
<select name="user_nationality" id="changecountry" class="input">
<option value="1" phonecode="+62">Indonesia</option>
<optgroup label="Other Countries">
    <option value="2" phonecode="+44">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="3" phonecode="+1">United States of America</option>
</optgroup>
```

```
<script>
$('#changecountry').on('change', function() {
    var phonecode = $('option:selected', this).attr('phonecode');
    $('#userphonearea').val(phonecode);
});
</script>
```